# Truecrypt in place decryption. Is this possible?

Tags: mac, encryption, truecrypt

I want to decrypt my entire partition and turn it back into standard NTFS.

I encrypted a large partition on my 1TB drive before I took it through the airport.
For this I used the in place method on truecrypt for win7.

I'm on a mac now and there doesn't seem to be any way to decryppt the drive in place. It mounts fine, but I don't want to buy another drive just so I can shift files around.

The drive is hooked up via USB. Would this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The feasibility is a function of your partition type,

> How to Remove Encryption
>
> Please note that **TrueCrypt can in-place decrypt only system partitions and system drives** (select System > Permanently Decrypt System Partition/Drive). If you need to remove encryption (e.g., if you no longer need encryption) from a non-system volume, [please follow these steps](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=removing-encryption).

The steps there suggest that you mount the non-system volume and copy data out.

Answer (score 1):

This (System > Permanently Decrypt System Partition/Drive) will leave you with a non-bootable partition. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Why does it make it not bootable any more?

Comment: Permanently Decrypt System Partition worked fine for me, my formerly-encrypted drive was bootable afterwards.  However, it ONLY works for system partitions.